# Custom Property Editor returns object Umbraco

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to create a custom Property Editor in Umbraco.

Package.manifest

```
{
    propertyEditors: [
        {
            alias: "Notification Ribbon",
            name: "Notification Ribbon",
            editor: {
                view: "~/App_Plugins/NotificationRibbon/NotificationRibbon.html"
            }          
        }
    ],
    javascript: [
        '~/App_Plugins/NotificationRibbon/NotificationRibbon.controller.js'
    ]
}
```

and in my controller

```
angular.module("umbraco").controller("NotificationRibbon.Controller", function($scope) {
    $scope.opennotification = function() {

        if (!$scope.control) {
            $scope.control = {}
        }
        if (!$scope.model) {
            $scope.model = {}
        }


        $scope.overlay = {
            title: "Nottification ribbon",
            view: "/ultradata/Views/common/overlays/notificationribbon/notificationribbon.html",
            rteeditor: $scope.model.value.rteeditor,
            NotifyLinkClass: $scope.model.value.NotifyLinkClass,
            Location: $scope.model.value.Location,
            ButtonValue: $scope.model.value.editModel,
            show: true,
            submit: function(model) {
                $scope.overlay.show = false;
                $scope.overlay = null;
                $scope.model.value = {};
                $scope.model.value.rteeditor = model.rteeditor.value;
                $scope.model.value.NotifyLinkClass = model.NotifyLinkClass;
                $scope.model.value.Location = model.Location;
                $scope.model.value.ButtonValue = model.ButtonValue;

            },
            close: function(oldModel) {
                $scope.overlay.show = false;
                $scope.overlay = null;
            }
        }

    }

});
```

the Property editor value is being stored like this on the server:

```
{
        "id": 19151,
        "alias": "not",
        "value": {
            "rteeditor": "<p>fghfhfghfgh</p>"
        }
    }
```

When I tried to take the value and display the notification Text value in Razor code

```
<div class="gayaaa">@Umbraco.Field("not")</div>
```

the Result returning the Entire object in Screen

[image]

Comment: Parse The Value using Json.Convert And use it how do u like 
u stored JavaScript object inside of the value now the Cshtml sees it as string so prase it using razor=>json convert 
or using notmal java script

Comment: What are you expecting as a result? Can you rephrase your post so that it is clearer what the question is?

Comment: hi i needs to show the values in div tag lets sat value.rteeditor inside the div it have return the value

Comment: hi @IbraHimM.Nada i would like to know the syntax i m new to razor so please let me know :)

Comment: at top of the page put @using System.Text 
then
you have the razor block
@{
Dynamic deCodedVar = Json.Decode(Umbraco.Field("not"));
}
then inside of you div put 
<div class="gayaaa">@deCodedVar.rteeditor</div>